# Loop through JQuery selector using TypeScript for...of

Tags: jquery, typescript

I prefer the TypeScript `for`loop over the JQuery `each()`.

I.e. because `return` and `break` work more like expected.

Is there an easy way to loop through a JQuery object using TypeScript?

```
let $elements = $('.text-element');

// error: Type 'JQuery' is not an array type or a string type.
for ( let $element of $elements )
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to return a iterable of the DOM elements (not jQuery elements):

```
let $elements = $('.text-element');

for (let element of $elements.get()) {
  let $element = $(element);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of `$('.text-element')` is not a real `Array`. Try creating an `Array` from it, first:

```
let $elements = Array.from($('.text-element'));

for ( let $element of $elements )
{
}
```

Comment: Is Array.from new? The 2.8 typings don't seem to recognize it.

Comment: It's part of the ES6 spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Answer (score 1):

Because [`jQuery's class selector`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) doesn't return an iterator, but a jQuery object. To use a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) syntax you need to make it an array-like iterable using [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```js
$(function() {
  const elements = Array.from($('.text-element'));

  for (const element of elements) {
    console.log(element.innerHTML);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text-element">
  10
</div>
<div class="text-element">
  20
</div>
<div class="text-element">
  30
</div>
```

Comment: Is Array.from new? The 2.8 typings don't seem to recognize it.

Comment: if your browser supports ES6 it should be available

Answer (score 0):

jQuery collections have been iterable since v1.12.0 and v2.2.0  ([PR](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1693), [commit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/bb026fc12c3c2ad37f47f0919e484bddcdc3d291#diff-7eb52b366866677666470e019283c8ea)), which were released in [January 2016](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/08/jquery-2-2-and-1-12-released/):

> #### Symbol/iterator support
>
> We've added support for the Symbol type and iterators via `Symbol.iterator` added in ES6/ES2015. "Symbol" will be detectable with `jQuery.type`, and jQuery objects can be iterated with `for-of` where supported.
>
> ```js
> for (element of $elements) {
>  console.log(element);
> }
> ```

Sounds like you just need to update your jQuery.